# Add Fadein Effect in Slideshow

Tags: javascript, css

Learning to build slideshow from w3school...

Well I've tried to change the animation duration in the css but nothing work

Can anyone tell how can I add fade in effect from the slideshow?

Comment: You should mention what you've tried (the code) in the question rather than pasting a link

Comment: You can use the `animation-delay` property to add delays to css transitions, what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

To delay the time, change this number (2000) to something else in the showSlides function:

```
 setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
```

To change the fade, edit the fade classes in the css:

```
    /* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```